# Pthreads: Relation between main thread and subthread stack sizes

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads

I am trying to understand the stack allocation of pthreads library in Linux. Here are few questions:

A) What is main thread ? - Is that the thread running C `main(`) program?

B) How much is stack allocation of main threads? Is that the `ulimit -s` size ?

C) How much is stack allocation of sub-threads? Is that the `ulimit -s` size ?

D) The stack size of main thread and other threads are dependent ?

E) The process stack and thread stack are shared? How do I decide process stack (say `a.out`) size.

F) Does these information vary between NPTL and LinuxThreads implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A: Yes
B: Yes
C: Maybe.

If pthread_attr_t used at thread creation did not specify stack size, and if `ulimit -s` is not unlimited, then `ulimit -s` will determine the stack size of a newly created thread.

D: Question is unclear. They are not dependent on each other, but they do both depend on `ulimit -s` under certain conditions.

E. Yes and no. They are shared in the sense of memory visibility -- the main thread can read and write other thread's stack variables, and vice versa. But each thread executes on its own stack, and if ever two threads started to execute on the same stack, that would be a disaster.

F. No.

Comment: For question D, the process stack is another term for main thread stack ? Or it is a different stack ?

Comment: @LunarMushrooms Yes, process stack is another term for main thread's stack.